# Web Service returning many values

Tags: android, web-services

I am doing r&d in android pagination in table view.

I want a web service that can return many values so that i can populate in the tableview and implement pagination in that. Can someone tell such web service.

Comment: i want such web service Wsdl link

Comment: Then what the mean of "Web Service returning many values" ????

Comment: Your subject and your question are different .

Comment: I want a web service link which returns many values like country names or some series of values so that i can use it for pagination

Comment: i want to use a existing web service obo like names of countries

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For that you have to go for Web services. Here are some of quick link may this help you.

http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/03/03/how-to-consume-web-services-from-android-applications-using-ksoap2/

http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-xml-binding-simple-tutorial.html

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-parsing-web-service-response-part-1/

Comment: Nirav i want a wsdl link that give countries names at same time ,thanks for your answer but i already know how to use a web-service

Comment: http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries

Comment: Nirav how can i store the values in String array

Comment: Using XML parsing . do some google. If you can get proper solutions . then tell me , I wil create demo and send you .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525822/table-pagination-table-layout-web-service-using-xml-parser nirav please can u give some solution for this

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer : give your gmail id and come in chat

Comment: vivekcareer123@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). It will send you many results that you could use to create a pagination process. Check out the [GET mentions_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) and its example.

Edit:
The [GET SEARCH](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) is more relevant to what you want to do.
You could for example use a request like this one :

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=<A QUERY THAT SHOULD RETURN MANY TWEETS>&rpp=<THE NUMBER OF TWEETS YOU WANT PER PAGE>&page=<THE PAGE YOU WANT TO GET ACCORDING TO RPP>&result_type=mixed
```

For example :

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bordeaux&rpp=20&page=1&result_type=mixed
```

It will return you a json object you could parse to display the results in your TableView. Then you will have to set the page= variable to make your pagination.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525822/table-pagination-table-layout-web-service-using-xml-parser can u give me a solution for this