# Android TableLayout Pagination Example Needed

Tags: android, pagination

I want a working demo of table pagination. Can some one give me link for table pagination. [Android table pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525822/table-pagination-table-layout-web-service-using-xml-parser).

I tried this link, but it's not working. Can some one tell me how to achieve this. I tried [PAGINATION LAYOUT](https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-PaginationLayoutSample/blob/master/src/com/paulononaka/PaginationLayout.java)

but this is not working. If this works can some tell the error in the program that I referred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use either the ViewPager or View Flipper for pagination.

This video shows how to use the view flipper.
[ViewFlipper Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xGIlaezMAU)
Just substitute your own view like TableRow.

If you want to use the ViewPager. [Android documentation has sample code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). (Edit: I should make note the viewPager requires the Support Library [This will explain how to install it. Its very easy](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Edit:
This is pseudo how you xml layout will look like.

> ```
> <tableLayout>
>     <viewFlipper>
>        <TableRow>
>         <Button>
>         </TableRow>
>
>  <TableRow>
>         <Button>
>         </TableRow>
>
>  <TableRow>
>         <Button>
>         </TableRow>
>  </viewFlipper>
> ```

```
<TableLayout>
```

Comment: had view on view flipper but task assigned for me is to do in tablelayout and table row with button click

Comment: Task assigned eh? Then I would ask for additional information from your instructor. 

The viewFlipper I believe however can be wrap around a table layout. I will modify my answer.

Comment: could u give any demo or example for viewfilpper wrapping table layout

Comment: Jerad Godreault do u have a demo for such conditions u specifed please give everyone can be benifited

Comment: why is my question not having research effect could some one explain as every pagination has listview and iam trying it in table layout,does that mean its not worth question

Comment: why is my question closed no one knows the answer?